# Java EE EJB 3.0 Glassfish

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, asynchronous, ejb-3.0, glassfish-3

I am getting this error on the Netbeans IDE with the codes.
Javadocs say that "asynchronous session bean invocation is not allowed in project targeting java ee 6 lite profile"

Javadocs say that "asynchronous session bean invocation is not allowed in project targeting java ee 6 lite profile"

Comment: Similar one, can refer here - https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=231202

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Java EE 6 comes with different profiles (i.e. Web/Lite profile and Full) not all functionality is supported in the Web/Lite profile. Especially the web profile only supports "EJB Lite" which comes without support for asynchronous EJBs have a look at the following article [which comes with a table describing the features in EJB Lite and 'regular' EJB](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1321142/Part-Three-New-Features-in-EJB-31)
So what you'd have to do is create a project with the full profile in Netbeans. This will give you access to @Asynchonous.

Answer (score 0):

It is solved by using Netbeans 7.2.1 Glassfish 3.1.2.2 bundled version.
Developer should be aware of version of Glassfish such as Web Profile or Full Platform.
If developers are working on EJB they should use Full Platform of Glassfish.